# Fetch value from collection without foreach loop

Tags: collection, performance, collection-filtering

I have a custom collection

```
$someCollection = Mage::getModel('mymodule/mymodel')->getCollection()
                           ->addFieldToSelect('some_field')
                           ->addFieldToFilter('another_field', array('eq' => $someValue));
```

Now consider, that **this collection will always return only one row** from the table, i.e.

```
$someCollection->getSize();
```

will always be "1". How to **get the value of "some_field"** without a foreach like:

```
foreach($someCollection as $row){
    $catchTheValue = $row->getSomeField();
}
```

I don't want to write foreach loop for one iteration. Can someone help?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you know that the collection just has one item then you could simply use `$someCollection->getFirstItem()`. This will give you the first and in your case only item. You can then continue to use the `getSomeField()` etc on this object.

A second option is possible to use `->load($attribute_value, 'attribute_code');` on the object but this can add overhead if the table is of a large size.

Comment: the second approach loads a complete model and initilizes it. I think what he wants is to avoid the overhead

Comment: @FabianBlechschmidt true I always have the gut feeling that loading the collection would take more overhead, but forget that it is often the case.

Comment: @FabianBlechschmidt: You're right that's a big table, I don't wanna load all the value instead only one column, so I don't want to use `load()`.

Comment: @Shathish Then I would use the first option.

Answer (score 4):

I checked the `Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract` and `Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Collection_Abstract` for any method that does this and there is none.

I think implementing your own ResourceModel is the best way. Just shot directly a query to the database and return the value.

Comment: yes I already thought about that, I'll do that in the next version of my module. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could make use of the underlying `Zend_Db_Select` object and execute it manually, bypassing the Magento model entirely:

```
$someFieldValue = $collection->getConnection()
     ->query($collection->getSelect())
     ->fetchColumn();
```

`fetchColumn()` returns the raw value of the first column returned by the query.

Note that this will only work if you don't rely on any Magento events or special attribute models.

Answer (score 0):

There is this one method `getAllIds()` in `Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Collection_Abstract`. It return an array containing primary key of all rows.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
$someFieldList = array_map(function($item){
  return $item['some_field'];
}, $collection->toArray(['some_field'])['items']);
```

You can pass the list of fields to return as array to the toArray function.